# How to convert a Specified Font ASCII to Unicode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode, ascii

Can anyone have an idea about how to convert specified FONT ASCII to UNICODE?
I have a situation where I need to do it like this..
ie if im specifying "Tahoma" as font it should convert all the character ASCII which is in Tahoma font to UNICODE data.

Please help me in this.
I searched a lot.. Everywhere it is only conversion of normal ASCII to Unicode not with specified font..

Comment: It is not clear what you want. The font has nothing to do with the encoding.

Comment: Do you have an example? Unicode code-points are... code-points. Encodings are encodings. And fonts are fonts... Do fonts contain additional mapping data ? (I'm pretty ignorant to the internals of fonts, but if you are referring to something specific, perhaps link to the concept)

Comment: I have to work with iPhone apps and andr apps so in that if im able to show the font it will be easy for conversion....

Comment: Are you on about font-fallback, where by if a specific glyph isn't available in the current font the rendering system will fallback to a different font that does have the requested glyph?

Comment: Fonts do typically contain extra mapping data, and that has been used to provide access to different glyphs in the days before Unicode. But it's irrelevant now and doesn't seem to relate to whatever it is the quesrtion is about.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode merely represents a character - not the *style* of the character, which is defined by the font name.

So, the letters A B C £ $ and suchlike are all ASCII and Unicode characters.

If you want to make it possible for your users to enter text that is styled with a particular font in a Web application, you'll need to use a "rich text" or "HTML" editing control.

Comment: My problem is ill be having different languages in different fonts.. ie for eg spanish, it will be having different FONTS for the same language.. so i need to convert those into unicode...

Comment: Sorry, this still makes no sense. Spanish language can be represented using any font you need, the non-US-ASCII characters such as ñ should appear correctly in Arial, Tahoma, etc. on PC-family devices, or Helvetica, Times and suchlike on other systems. Could you describe exactly what your problem is and what's not working for you?